# How to set port to listen in c++ using libvlc?

Tags: visual-c++, media-player, vlc, libvlc

I have created a media player instance using libvlc which plays a video -
libvlc_media_player_play (mPlayerInstance)

Now, how can i make this player listen to specific port and play the content which is being streamed to that port ?

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1):

As the VLC command

```
libvlc_instance_t     *p_inst;
libvlc_media_t        *p_m;
libvlc_media_player_t *p_mp;
//...
p_inst = libvlc_new(0, NULL);
p_m = libvlc_media_new_path(p_inst, "rtp://@:<listenport>/path");    
p_mp = libvlc_media_player_new(p_inst);

libvlc_media_player_set_media(p_m);
```

When the stream begin, the vlc instance will start to play.